# Skipping test during maven compile

Tags: java, maven, testing, compiler-errors

I am trying to stop maven from compiling the Tests. I have already tried using `-DskipTests` and `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` . But neither stops maven from compiling the tests.

```
 mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests -T1C
```

I get errors in the tests.

The error message

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project pnd-lib: Compilation failure

Comment: maybe you can try a `-fn`, `--fail-never` NEVER fail the build, regardless of project result (the tests), or `-fae` if you are working with only one module, it executes the build but won't stop on failure

Comment: in that case, I get the error on Tests no matter what. But the good thing is that it shows all the errors in the module :-). So basically the compilation of tests are not skipped.

Comment: I am looking for an option with which I can have a failure only on main code errors and not test error.

Comment: Can you provide more infos about your testing framework, version maybe if you are using a surfire? because `-DskipTests` should do the job

Comment: added compile error

Comment: The jdk version? are using maven surfire plugin? jUnit 5?

Comment: JDK 1.8, maven-sure-fire not on the module level but on the project level. Junit 5 yes.

Comment: First you should try to get your project compiled properly afterwards check things like ignoring tests etc.

Comment: i am compiling my project. Since the tests are also compiled, I cannot complete the project compilation. The project is very large with so many modules. So removing tests files is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-DskipTests=true`

Works fine for me

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt work on mine.. Are there any build parameters that you have set in the project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the jupiter engine dependency inside your build configuration to run JUnit5 tests like so :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>

            <dependencies>
                <!-- to let surefire to run JUnit 4 but also JUnit 5 tests -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- JUnit 5 engine to run JUnit 5 tests -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also make sure you are using Jdk8 to run the build

And then `-DskipTests` should works for you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, however upgrade to the latest maven compiler plugin version (3.8.1) fixed the problem. I assume this is a bug in v3.6.0 of the plugin.